# I don't know why the hardhat installation isn't working

Tags: reactjs, installation, hardhat

I'm trying to create a next.js react project using hardhat for Ethereum smart contracting.

Here is what I installed: `npm install ethers hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers web3modal @openzeppelin/contracts ipfs-http-client axios`

This is what I see in my folder:

[image]

I don't understand why I don't see a `contracts`, `scripts` folder and files like `hardhat.config.js`. Did I do something wrong in my installation? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I downloaded the latest version of next-react like this: `npx create-next-app@latest {name}`

Comment: This could be a comment my friend